# Object doesn't support property or method 'coreUISelect'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I'm getting the error in title on this part:

```
$('select').coreUISelect('destroy')
           .coreUISelect({
                 appendToBody:true,
                 jScrollPane: { 
                     verticalDragMinHeight:20, 
                     verticalDragMaxHeight:20,
                     showArrows:true
                              }
                          });
```

Oddly, this is not happening everytime and I didn't see this in Chrome. It happens in IE11 and I have to do a few refreshes to see this happen. Any ideas?

Edit: Core UI Select is a plugin for styling selects, http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Select-Element-Styling-Plugin-coreUISelect.html

Comment: And what is `coreUISelect` ?

Comment: Not that this will fix your problem (necessarily) but you are missing a ` : ` in your example --  `jsScrollPane : {}`

Comment: Thanks @wahwahwah I forgot it here, now edited.

Comment: @adeneo It is a plugin, I edited with the link to it.

Comment: @Kuzgun a few refresh is strange...are you running the code in document.ready?

Comment: Yes I run it in document.ready. One thing I tried to add if($(select).length>0) and now I don't see it anymore, but I'm not sure if it is fixed because this doesn't come up on every page refresh.

Comment: @Kuzgun how are you filling the select? With an ajax call?

Comment: Yes, it is filled with ajax @IrvinDominin